# Does it require separate rtc::Runnable thread and PeerConnectionFactory object for each peer in webrtc native application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, webrtc, native

I am trying to create a native application using [WebRTC native APIs](https://webrtc.org/native-code/native-apis/). For the first peer I create a rtc::Runnable object and in its Run method create the PeerConnectionFactory object. Then from that object I create a peerconnection object and create offer and continue to set local and remote descriptions and ICE configuration etc. and all goes well.

Now I am trying to understand what should I do for the second peer from the same process. Do I need to create another rtc::Runnable thread or can I reuse it and its peer connection factory object to create a separate peerconnection object?

It could be somewhere in the documentation, but I could not find it. It is clear that I need a separate peer connection for each peer and separate observer objects for each of those connections.

It is more of a design question- using everything separate works of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peer connection factory should be shared by all peers, you don't need to have 2 factories. 
    So you can create connection as many you need with the same factory. When you create a peer you can also create a new observer, but you can have an observer which handle events the same for each peer.

Eg. from peer A you get a media stream and A's observer sends it to UI, then B also gives you it's stream then B's observer sends it to UI, if you have a common observer it can do the same for both.